# Partial string replace in jquery

Tags: javascript

Just wandering will it be possible to partially string replace in jquery?

I have try to using the following code, but this is not seem working for me:

```
var test = "testing_supplyAddress_001";
test.replace('supplyAddress', 'billingAddress');
```

I tried to replace only supplyAddress to billingAddress so the output will be testing_billingAddress _001

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery.  That's pure JavaScript.

Comment: This is not possible with jQuery as it does not provide any string manipulation functions. But you can use basic JavaScript like you already do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript strings are static and thus `.replace()` does not actually *modify* the string. You'll need to assign the value returned by the `.replace()` function back to the variable:

```
var test = "testing_supplyAddress_001";
test = test.replace('supplyAddress', 'billingAddress');
```

[Here's a demo showing this in action ->](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/FmH6p/)

Answer (score 2):

It works fine. It doesn't replace it in place though - the `replace()` method returns a new string.

```
var test = "testing_supplyAddress_001";
var newTest = test.replace('supplyAddress', 'billingAddress');
alert(newTest);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just plain old javascript - but will work with jQuery too.

```
var test = "testing_supplyAddress_001".replace('supplyAddress', 'billingAddress');
```